# Stop jQuery function from executing

Tags: jquery, execution

I want a *save* function to check if a session is set (using another function) and stop the base function from continuing, but the function seems to continue (not executable below):

```js
//1. Base save function

$("#save").click(function (e) {    
  e.preventDefault();
  //step 0 check if logged in
  checksession();
  console.log("teststop"); //just for testing
  //steps x continue execution of session exists
});

//2. Session check function
function checksession(){ 
    $.ajax({ 
 type: "GET",
 url:"xxxx/sessioncheck.php",
 dataType: "text",
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
     if(data == "no"){
  return;
            } else {} //continue 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous, that means the following code will continue executing and it's not blocking. Also even if this was intended to be a blocking call it wont work, `return` is only for the function it was called in. It doesn't propagate to the outer function that called and causes that one to return it nor should it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let `checksession`'s AJAX `success` callback be the function that performs the "save" operation (or not)

```
//1. Base save function

$("#save").click(function (e) {             
  e.preventDefault();
  //step 0 check if logged in
  checksession();
});


//2. Session check function

function checksession(){    
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url:"xxxx/sessioncheck.php",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
            if(data == "no")
            {
                console.log( "stop" );
            } else {
                console.log( "continue" ); 
                doSave();
            }   
        }
    });
}


//3. Perform save operation

function doSave() {
    //
    // proceed with the save operation
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#save").click(function (e) {    


  e.preventDefault();
  //step 0 check if logged in
  check();
if(check()==true){
continue;
}else{
stop
}
  console.log("teststop"); //just for testing
  //steps x continue execution of session exists
});

//2. Session check function
function check(){
var result=false;
    function checksession(){    
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url:"xxxx/sessioncheck.php",
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "no"){
            return;
                } else {
result=true;
} //continue    
            }
        });
    }
return result;
```

}